# What's the meaning of "不见面也有不见面的好"?

Tags: translation

I really couldn't understand the meaning of this sentences.

见面 means to meet, to see
不见面 means not meet, not see.

不见面也有不见面的好。

But I really couldn't get what it is saying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can break this up into three parts

1. 不见面 - to not meet
2. 也有 - also has
3. 不见面的好 -  the good aspect (or benefits) of not meeting

There's also benefits of not meeting (or not seeing (each other)).

Answer (score 5):

The construct **`(action) 也有 (same action) 的好`** is a generic way of expressing that the action (which is negative), in this case "*not meeting*", has some upside to it. So this sentence literally means: **"*there's a silver lining to not seeing you*."**

It seems you might have seen this in a list of romantic one-liners; in the original (不见面也有不见面的好，你永远是，我记忆中的样子), it goes on to explain the brighter side of not meeting is: "*you will always remain as you are now in my memories.*"

Answer (score 3):

something or somebody you meet will hurt again,
so have this sentence, not meet,sometimes good.

Answer (score 1):

a pretext for being unable to see someone whom you are longing to see. there may or may not be any real "benefits" in not seeing each other as the alleged "benefits" merely serve to provide a certain degree of comfort to a sad reality.

"也有" is "yes ... but". If not seeing each other is a good thing, you would simply say "不见面有不见面的好" (without the "也"). "也" gives away the fact the not seeing each other is bad (sad) and is definitely not something you want, but you try to conceal your true feeling by pretending that it is not as bad as it really is.

Answer (score 0):

If someone told you that, you can reply: 我知道，相见争如不见 or 相见不如怀念